# Target reference for each bar in Spotfire

Tags: bar-chart, spotfire

In Spotfire:
Is it possible to show target value reference line for each bar in a bar chart.
A way around that i am doing now is using combination chart. Refer screenshot.[image]

The problem here is that now i can not define a color by property to color bars using rules.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do it automatically without scripting but here is an example of how to do it by hand.

**Right click on your bar chart and go to the Lines & Curves section:**

[image]

Here you can see I've added 4 lines based on percentage of the data.

**You can do this or add lines of set values using the Add button in the top right and selecting Horizontal Line.**

[image]

Notice I've added the line name as the description of the percentage it is, hovering over will show an actual value so it may better to do this if it isn't clear what the value represents.

This is what it produces:

[image]

To make it better match your question I've added 2 more employees and coloured by employee instead, I've also set fixed targets for each person rather than percentages and renamed them to make sure it is clear which line applies to which person in case the colour isn't enough.

**Using the Settings -> Appearance section back in the first picture change the colour of the lines to match the fields they represent.**

[image]

Like I said at the start you should be able to create a script to do this for you but that is another question.

Comment: thanks Ryanfae for the reply. I actually tried this way around also but here we have lines as many as number of bars spreading throughout the chart which looks messy when we have more number of bars.

Comment: Hmmm yeah it would if you had many lines. I tried to get something working by having another table with lines where the Y value was the target and the X values were 0.5 above and below the X-axis value (so in your chart you'd have 0.5 and 1.5 for the 1 entry) but couldn't get it to work. Maybe something in that?